# it's a qst about expr and a qst about multiplications

Tags: bash

My bash consider "*" like the variable to show all the files in current directory

So if i do `expr 1 * 1` it will output

> expr 1 Desktop Documents Downloads[...] 1

(for `~/` current directory)

So expr willn't work. But for other operand it works

(sorry for the title, the bot refuses "expr and multiplications")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is escape the `*` symbol

```
expr 1 \* 1
```